# Android how to open a menu / voice recognition

Tags: java, android, button, menu, voice-recognition

Android Studio here. I am trying to open the menu (the three dot one in the right upper corner) but without clicking it. I am using a voice recognition commands.

I already tried to call it in many ways, e.g. openOptionsMenu();,  MapsActivityCurrentPlace.this.openOptionsMenu(); etc. but it didn't work, the menu doesn't open.

```java
// This is my menu - current_place_menu
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.current_place_menu, menu);
        //optionsMenu = menu;
        return true;
    }

// Later in the code, this is the place I want to open my menu by recognizing the "menu" command

private int voiceR() {
        switch (OPERATOR) {
                case 'M':
                //getMenuInflater();
                //openOptionsMenu();
               // MapsActivityCurrentPlace.this.openOptionsMenu(); // activity's onCreateOptionsMenu gets called
               // optionsMenu.performIdentifierAction(R.id.groupp, 0);
                //optionsMenu.performIdentifierAction(R.menu.current_place_menu, 0);
                //getMenuInflater();
               // MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
               // inflater.inflate(R.menu.current_place_menu, optionsMenu);
                //MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
                //inflater.inflate(R.menu.current_place_menu, menu);
                //Inflater.performIdentifierAction(R.id.groupp, 0);
                //mShowMenu = true;
                //invalidateOptionsMenu();
                break;
            case 'T':
                break;
        }
        return -999;
    }
```

Expected result would be the opened menu with an implemented list. For now, it recognizes the command but doesn't open the menu.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried with other stuff and still can't open the Menu.
Maybe my question was a bit twisted but does anyone know how to perform a click on menu without actually clicking it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that's what helped finally:

```
switch (OPERATOR) {
            case 'M':
            optionsMenu.performIdentifierAction(R.id.groupp, 0);
            break;
```

where groupp is the id of the menu.